# Differenze tra "muro" e "parete"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, difference

"Muro" e "parete": questi due vocaboli mi sono sempre sembrati molto simili. Non capisco se ci sono differenze di uso o di significato tra loro. Per esempio, se sto parlando dell'interno di un'abitazione, cosa devo usare: "muro" o "parete"? Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire i miei dubbi?

Comment: *Parete* è più specifico di *muro* (nel caso di abitazioni). Ha anche significati particolari che *muro* non ha.

Comment: @egreg: Cosa vuoi dire con "più specifico"? Potresti farmi un esempio?

Comment: Per abitazioni puoi usare entrambi però, per un giardino, puoi dire muro di cinta e non parete di cinta...

Answer (score 6):

Con la parola *parete* si indica uno dei lati di un *muro*. Il muro è definito come una struttura parallelepipeda dall'altezza e dalla larghezza notevolmente più spessi rispetto alla terza dimensione (lo spessore). Perciò ogni muro avrà due pareti.

Guardando in questo link http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/muro/ c'è la definizione di muro e negli esempi è possibile leggere:

> *muro a scarpa*, nel quale una parete è, anziché verticale, obliqua, in modo che lo spessore della struttura sia maggiore in basso che in alto.

Nel parlato comune, parlando dell'interno di una casa, le due parole sono utilizzate per dire la stessa cosa. Ciò probabilmente è dovuto al fatto che il muro ha un solo lato in una stanza (quindi una sola parete per stanza legata a un determinato muro).

Comment: Interessante distinzione questa della parete come “lato” di un muro, ma è registrata dai dizionari? Nel [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/parete/) trovo «Nelle costruzioni, elemento verticale, piano o curvo, di un edificio, con prevalente funzione di separare i diversi ambienti sia tra di loro sia verso l’esterno», tanto è vero che si parla di “parete divisoria”, mentre lo Zingarelli usa addirittura esplicitamente la parola “muro” per definire la parete: «muro interno di edifici, generalmente di piccolo spessore, per dividere i vani, talvolta dotato di funzione portante».

Comment: @DaG, in alcuni dizionari (Garzanti è uno che ho sottomano ma non posso raggiungerlo online) uno dei significati è di *superficie* che delimita uno spazio. Poi c'è l'esempio della grotta che ha pareti ma non muri... ma non credo che anche in architettura ci sia la vera e propria distinzione tra muro e parete visto che si parla di pareti portanti con l'ovvio significato di "muro" e non della sola superficie dello stesso (i miei vecchi libri usavano "superficie muraria" per indicare un lato del muro e non parete)

Comment: @DaG purtroppo non ho dizionari sotto mano, però treccani.it dava questa definizione calzante. @ Erik si, parete ha anche altri significati.. però io nella mia risposta ho dato per scontato il significato legato al muro.

Comment: a me convince, ma vedi [etimo](http://www.etimo.it/?term=parete)

Answer (score 0):

Un muro può avere comunque altre sfaccettature nel linguaggio.

- Un proverbiale **muro di gomma** è in realtà una *parete* di gomma cui ci troviamo davanti quando una persona non vuole ascoltarci
- Francesco ha recentemente pronunciato una famosa frase "costruiamo ponti, non **muri**" con esplicito riferimento alle **barriere** non necessariamente in *muratura* costruite in USA e Ungheria
- Da notare **le mura** come una specifica forma plurale riferita a pareti di cinta di un castello/prigione costriuiti in ambiente esterno e non dotati di copertura superiore (soffitto). Cioè mentre *i muri* di un palazzo dividono uno spazio esterno da uno interno sul piano tridimensionale, *le mura* sono generalmente scavalcabili per via aerea

Nell'uso comune, volendo sottolineare il commento di @DaG sui muri e le pareti delle grotte, mi va di notare che non conosco un solo utilizzo della parola *muro* che non riguardi costruzioni **artificiali**, mentre la parete rocciosa, anche se ottenuta scavando resta pur sempre un artefatto naturale

Fonte: me stesso, madrelingua

Answer (score 0):

In architettura la [**parete**](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/parete/) è un elemento che separa diversi ambienti tra loro o con l'esterno. Per analogia, vengono chiamate pareti anche gli elementi che separano degli spazi in elementi non architettonici, come "le pareti di una vettura"; può indicare anche la superficie interna di un elemento cavo come "parete dello stomaco" o "pareti di un baule".

Credo che il [muro](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/M/muro.shtml), fatta eccezione per gli utilizzi metaforici, sia considerabile, in architettura o edilizia, principalmente una parete costituita in pietra, mattoni o laterizi, con lo scopo di delimitare uno spazio o sostenere strutture.

Un altro utilizzo di muro, che lo differenzia dalla parete, è quello in cui lo si utilizza come sinonimo di barriera, anche in senso metaforico, come "muro di silenzio" oppure "muro di nebbia".